# Application stop When using Camera

Tags: android, cordova, camera

In my Cordova2.9.0 based Android Application i have include camera functionality.When i take Camera using Galazy S3 the application restarts,I found some solution links like
    [1.Link1](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_camera_crash_on_android_4_1_2_samsung_galaxy_s3_htc)   [2.Link2](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/samsung_galaxy_s3_camera_crash)

and added changes with

**Android manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

But still the is not fixed.Here my camera Code

```
function capturePhoto()
{
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess,fail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
}
                            );
}
```

Can any one please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If possible post your logcat message and give your full js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I share my working code.

Please try with that and tell me if you got solution.

JS Part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var pictureSource;
            var destinationType;
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
            }
            function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {      
              var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
              largeImage.style.display = 'block';
              largeImage.src = imageURI;
            }
            function capturePhoto() {     
              navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
            }
            function onFail(message) {
              alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }
        </script>
```

HTML Part:

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button><br />
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="largeImage" src="" />
```

Rest of them config.xml and manifest.xml are same what you mentioned.

Comment: I don't know about 4.1.4, But I tested with 4.1.2. works fine. Did you tried with my code.

Answer (score 0):

app/res/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
```

have you placed it.....

Comment: in app/res/xml/config.xml its added like `<feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>`

Comment: navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType : destinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType : Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    });

Answer (score 0):

It solved after I restart the phone (Samsung Grant android 4.1.2)